# How to use ArrayList comparator with custom insertion sort method

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, comparator

This is an assignment, I can't post the entire code, but I really need understand what I'm doing wrong. I'm sure its a rookie mistake.:(

I had to construct a custom sort method,that sorts specific properties of my arraylist objects. I've created different Comparators to address the different elements within the objects I want sorted.

*edit added more code

sort utility method (parameters required):

```
public class CarManage{
    private ArrayList <Car> carList;    //carList defined

    public class Sorts {
        public static void sorts(Car[]carList, int size, Comparator <Car> someComparator)   //given parameters not allowed to modify
        {
            //sorts arrayList(carList) objects using an insertion sort algorithm.
        }
    }
}   //end class
```

I try call the sort method, to specify which properties I need sort, but alas it rejects the first parameters.

```
 public void sortByVinNumber(){
  VinNumComparator vnc = new VinNumComparator();//one of many comparators
  Sorts vncSort = new Sorts();

  for(int i = 0; i < carList.size(); i++){
        if(vnc.compare(carList.get(i-1), carList.get(i)) > 0){           
        vncSort.sorts(Car[]carList, 2, vnc);//not working here rejects first parameter
        ///vncSort.sorts(carList,2,vnc)///doesn't work
        }
    }
 }
```

I'm not sure why it won't accept my parameter? Could it be a pass-reference mistake? Or am I possibly calling the method wrong?

Comment: Don't put `Car[]` in front `carList` in the parameter list. You only do that to variables when you are declaring them

Comment: I've tried this.Then the entire sort method is rejected, and gives me the error "The method sorts(Car[], int, Comparator<Car>) in the type Sorts is not applicable for the arguments (ArrayList<Car>, int, VinNumberComparator)"

Comment: Where do you define `carList`?  Show us that line.  That method is expecting an `ArrayList` not an array.

Comment: How about implementing your Car class with `Comparable<Car>` interface and declaring override method of `compareTo(Car anotherCar)` ? In compareTo you can declare your own logic of comparing Car instances.  Then you can use simple `Collections.sort( carArrayList )`.

Comment: @C.T No, when you are calling `sorts`, don't type `Car[]` before `carList`. Only do that when declaring objects

Comment: Also, the OP shows a declaration for a method that takes a `Car[]`, but the error message shows it wants an `ArrayList`.  I think he's calling the wrong class or something.

Comment: I've added the carList, it used through the entire program in several different methods and works fine. @t4dohx I would love to use Arrays/Collections.sort. It would make my life so much easier I have to create a custom sort.

Comment: Your question should really include the exact, verbatim errors and the lines that generate them. Edit question to add these things, don't add them in comments.

Comment: @C.T - by implementing `Comparable<T>` generic interface, you 'tell' the compiler how to compare two objects of `T` type, (in your case `Car` class) by overriding `compareTo(T object)`. If your class implements the interface, you can use `Collections.sort(arrayListOfCarObjects)` or `Arrays.sort(arrayOfCarObjects)` without doing anything else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call the method like so:

```
vncSort.sorts(carList, 2, vnc);
```

Also, it seems like you're confusing an array with an ArrayList. An Array of Car would be `Car[]`. An `ArrayList<Car>` is a `List` which accepts and produces `Car` types. The reason it's called `ArrayList` is because it's backed internally by an array.